# Import methods on an object in Scala

Tags: scala, dsl

I am trying to write a DSL with Scala.  I would initially like to be able to write things like

```
   defType "foo"
```

when using it.

I had thought that the following should work:

*src/main/scala/Test.scala*

```
class Dsl {
    def defType(name: String) = "dummy"
}
object Dsl {
    def apply() = new Dsl()
}

class UseDsl {
    def foo() = {
        val dsl = Dsl()
        import dsl._

        dsl defType "foo"
        defType("foo")
        defType "foo"
    }
}
```

This fails to compile:

```
[error] Test.scala:15:17: ';' expected but string literal found.
[error]         defType "foo"
[error]                 ^
[error] one error found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

Explicitly giving `dsl` works with spaces to separate the method names and arguments.

Implicitly using `dsl` and parentheses to indicate arguments vs method names works.

Attempting to use both of them together fails.

Is there a way to get that to work?

Once this is working, I plan to extend the DSL to support things like

```
defType "foo"
   -- "bar1" :: "quz"
   -- "bar2" :: "quz"
```

which would be equivalent to

```
dsl.defType("foo").
   --(ImplicitClass("bar1", dsl).::("quz")).
   --(ImplicitClass("bar2", dsl).::("quz"))
```

Is this something that I will be able to get to work?  I think the `ImplicitClass` would work with a declaration like

```
def implicit ImplicitClass(a: String, implicit dsl: Dsl) = ...
```

but clearly, my understanding of how you can get Scala to add things to your code is imperfect.

If it won't work, what are some minimal additions that would let it work?

*build.sbt*

```
ThisBuild / organization := "test"
ThisBuild / version := "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.12.8"


//
// Projects
//
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `method argument` is not valid. For infix method calls without parentheses, you *have* to do

```
val1 method1 val2 method2 val3 ...
```

This chain can end in a method without arguments or in the last method's argument, and the first one is not too safe.

Even for members of current type, you need to do `this method1 ...` and can't omit `this` as in `this.method1(...)`.